# Computing lag in Hive by a variable

Tags: hadoop, hive

My input table looks like:

```
guest_id    days
101          79
101          70
101          68
101          61
102          101
102          90
102          55
103          99
103          90
```

Note that, days are in descending order,by guest_id

Desired output table:

```
guest_id    days     days_diff
101          79      0
101          70      9
101          68      2
101          61      7
102          101     0
102          90      11
102          55      35
103          99      0
103          90      9
```

days_diff is the first order difference by guest_id (not throughout days column)

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a unique `id` column as well (otherwise Hive doesn't know about the order of your rows).

Then you can just self join on `id=id+1` to get your differences:

```
select a.guest_id, 
       a.days, 
       case when a.guest_id = b.guest_id then b.days-a.days else 0 end days_diff
from 
input a
join input b on a.id=b.id-1
```

**Edit:** As pointed out by Kunal in the comments, Hive does have a Lag window function which requires a `PARTITION BY ... ORDER BY` clause; you still need something to order your table by, for example if you have a `date` column you  would used this like the following:

```
SELECT guest_id, 
       days, 
       LAG(days, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY guest_id ORDER BY date)
FROM input;
```

Comment: how does it take care that lag difference is computed within a guest_id?

Comment: I want to use the following type of query:                                                                                CREATE TABLE output AS SELECT gst_i, diff, LAG(diff, 1, 0) as lag_diff FROM input BY gst_i;         this works well in sql

Comment: you can't use `lag` in hive as far as I know, you have to do a self join. i've edited my answer to show how to make the first lag equal to zero for each guest

Comment: there's a function called LAG in hive, but usage has been done using partition and all which I couldn't understand  https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics